# php replace if two or more non alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have been trying to replace a portion of a string if two of more non alphanumeric characters are found.

I have it partly working but can not replace when a underscore is in there.

This is what i am trying.

```
$str = "-dxs_  s";

$str = preg_replace('/\W{2,}|\_{2,}/', ' ', $str);
```

reults in `-dxs_ s` should be `-dxs s`.

So how do you replace if two or more non alphanumeric characters are found in a string?

Comment: "Charters" -> "Characters" For some reason there's no edit button on this question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\W|_){2,}/', ' ', $str);
```

What this is doing is grouping the "non-word or underscore" part and applies the 2+ quantifier to it as a whole.

**[See it in action](http://regexr.com?2vcng)**.

Comment: Your saying this will result in `-dxss`, well is this the case only if the `replacement` is empty with no space?

Comment: @david: Doh! Yes, I didn't see that space between the quotes. False alarm, sorry!

Comment: Your right, it is kinda hard to notice the extra space, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`\W` also excludes `_` therefore you need your own characters class :

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}/
```

or

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-z\d]{2,}/i', ' ', $subject);
```

Comment: +1 works well, Thanks for explaining about how \W excludes underscore